# Adding a template and keep pdf tags?

Tags: pdf, itext

i am trying to work with marked content at the moment and stumbled upon a little problem.

Currently i add predefined PDFs onto my new PDF with the following code:

```
        // we only use the first page to import
        PdfImportedPage importedPage = m_writer.GetImportedPage(target, 1);

        // calculate the transformation matrix 
        // set up the affine transform 
        float angle = (float)(item.rotationAngle * (Math.PI / 180.0f));
        float a = item.scalingX * (float)(Math.Cos(angle));
        float b = item.scalingY * (float)(Math.Sin(angle));
        float c = (-item.scalingX) * (float)(Math.Sin(angle));
        float d = (item.scalingY) * (float)(Math.Cos(angle));            

        // output
        cb.AddTemplate(importedPage, a, b, c, d, item.x, item.y);
```

This works just fine and allows me to add multiple pdfs like pictures on the same page.

Now here is my problem, when i do something like this the tag "Figure" won't show up in the tags list:

```
        cb.BeginMarkedContentSequence(PdfName.FIGURE);

        // we only use the first page to import
        PdfImportedPage importedPage = m_writer.GetImportedPage(target, 1);

        // calculate the transformation matrix ( scaling and rotation !! counter clockwise )
        // set up the affine transform 
        float angle = (float)(item.rotationAngle * (Math.PI / 180.0f));
        float a = item.scalingX * (float)(Math.Cos(angle));
        float b = item.scalingY * (float)(Math.Sin(angle));
        float c = (-item.scalingX) * (float)(Math.Sin(angle));
        float d = (item.scalingY) * (float)(Math.Cos(angle));            

        // output
        cb.AddTemplate(importedPage, a, b, c, d, item.x, item.y);

        cb.EndMarkedContentSequence();
```

Is there a way to add pdf tags to an imported page or is this the wrong approach ? Afaik GetImportedPage() drops the tags and that is why i can't work with "pre tagged" items.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's the wrong approach and it's the wrong iText version for this kind of work. Try iText 7. But be aware that merging structure trees of different documents is not trivial at all.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie can you give me a hint what the correct approach would be and is there already an C# Version of iText 7 ( because i am stuck with c# ).

Comment: Yes, there is a C# version of iText 7, and no: I haven't had a chance to look at merging Tagged PDFs myself. I only know that it was on the technical road map for iText 7, and as far as I know, it has been implemented.